# Aramaic view in Google Chrome

Tags: mac

I cannot see the characters of Aramaic in the page http://pes.scripturetext.com/matthew/1.htm How can I see them? 
any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download and install a Syriac font from someplace like

http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Syriac.html

In more detail the installation is documented [here](http://www.bethmardutho.org/index.php/syriac-mac.html):

1. Download the [Meltho Syriac fonts](http://www.bethmardutho.org/images/fonts/melthofonts-1.21.zip)
2. Unzip the file, select all the OTF files and press <kbd>Cmd-O</kbd> to open/install them
3. You may get some warnings about small font errors, just proceed nevertheless
4. Go to Fontbook and Disable the Damascus font.  It has a bug which interferes with Syriac fonts.
5. Fonts should now display correctly in documents and browsers

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the addition, Patrix.  I added a point to take care of a display problem I can see with character U+0718, caused by a bug in the Damascus font.  But I cannot change the graphic at the moment...

Comment: No problem. What I see does not make much sense to me anyway :-)

Comment: Graphic has been changed to reflect disabling of Damascus font.

Answer (score 0):

OsX doesnt support Syriac. So I think I'll use windows parallel with OsX. that looks the only solution for now, until Apple solves the problem.

Comment: Did you try to install an appropriate font as the other answer recommends?

Comment: Could you explain the problem you think needs solving?  With RTL scripts some apps (like MS Word) don't work right, others do.

Comment: OS X supports Hebrew and Arabic. Perhaps you mean there is no Syriac keyboard?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus  If that's what he means, you just need to download it, as you do with the font.  There's one available at https://www.box.com/s/15eb1f291cab58a4569e

Comment: I tried to install all fonts 1-by-1. and then i learned that OsX doesnt support Syriac. I installed vMWare and windows, and use the webpage on windows and just switch back.

Comment: I still don't understand it when you say you "learned that OS X doesn't support Syriac".  That doesn't make sense. I have given you a picture just above of my Mac displaying your Syriac webpage.  How can you then think it is not supported?

Comment: I don't understand either. There isn't an issue of supporting a particular language. There's an issue of supporting RTL languages, which Os X does, and of course having fonts with Syriac characters. My new best guess is that he is visiting a web page with a particular encoding which was not auto-detected by his Mac browser, but is by IE or whatever he is using on the Dark Side.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus But I have visited the same web page he asked about with the same browser and provided a picture for him to see.  It would be really helpful if he would specify the "problem" he thinks needs to be solved.  At the moment he has posted info regarding support which appears to be simply wrong, and I am sure he would not want to do that.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus PS There was a time a few years ago when OS X did not support Syriac, even though it did support Arabic.  Perhaps Serdar has taken his view from  old published stuff that has not been updated. Also a couple apps like Pages and MS Word still cannot do it right, and perhaps he is referring to them specifically.

Comment: yeah, Tom u right. I'm sorry i installed the font at first and didnt work. Now I deleted all of the fonts I installed earlier and did as in the instructions. I can view the page now. But pdf file is still same as past. some of the syriac and arabic words in pdf file are still missing. But at least I can view the page without Windows. Thank you all guys.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Serdar.  I am surprised a pdf file would not work, since fonts are supposed to be embedded and it should not matter what system is reading them.  
Could you send me an example or provide a url so I can test one (tom at bluesky dot org).